# Pandas DataFrame - groupby / remove duplicates and keep max of a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame with the following structure. I am trying to group by / de-duplicate conditional on keeping the row with max value of one of the columns `cnt`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
                   'name': ['p1', 'p1', 'p2', 'p2'],
                   'size': [10, 10, 20, 20],
                   'yr': [1990, 1990, 2000, 2000],
                   'res': [1, 2, 1, 2],
                   'cnt': [100, 80, 220, 400]
                  })
```

Expected Output:

```
name size yr    res cnt
p1   10   1990  1   100
p2   20   2000  2   400
```

Comment: The best solution is to use `groupby.idxmax`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
df.sort_values(['cnt']).drop_duplicates(['name'], keep='last')
```